# Joomla htaccess redirect to mobile site

Tags: .htaccess, joomla2.5

I am trying to get this joomla site to redirect to a subdomain called mobile.backuptoweb.co.uk when used on mobile devices. But I also want to keep the existing rewrite rules that ensure all users are redirected to the www. url and trailing / are removed.

Currently it just redirects into an infinate loop when view on a mobile device.

htaccess:

```
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##


## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.

# mobile site redirection
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.*).backuptoweb.co.uk/.*$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera          mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.backuptoweb.co.uk/$1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^backuptoweb.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.backuptoweb.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

# index.php to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

RewriteBase /

 ## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
 #
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
 #

 ## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be feasible to redirect all mobile traffic to your mobile subdomain and have a second .htaccess file there where you do the mobile tests and rewrites?

To check if I understand your comments correctly,

**For non-mobile visitor**

http://backuptoweb.co.uk/something redirects to http://www.backuptoweb.co.uk/something

**For mobile visitor**

http://backuptoweb.co.uk/something redirects to http://www.mobile.backuptoweb.co.uk/something

**except** if they are coming from your mobile site. If this is the case you want

http://backuptoweb.co.uk/something redirecting to http://www.backuptoweb.co.uk/something

---

What do you think of this for the logic and order?

- Rewrite index.php to / (definitely don't use [L] flag)
- Check if mobile visitor and coming from mobile site. If yes use Rewrite with [L] and send to http://www.backuptoweb.co.uk/something
- Check if mobile visitor (and not coming from mobile site. If yes use Rewrite with [L] and send to http://www.backuptoweb.co.uk/something
- Rewrite no-www to www.backuptoweb.co.uk/something with [R=301,L]

Some of the flags probably need work.

---

See how this works for you. Be sure to clear you browser cache as well when testing.

If there are any mod_rewrite gurus out there, I'd also welcome suggestions for improvement

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Jooomla stuff here

# rewrite index.php to /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
# RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://www.backuptoweb.co.uk$1 [R=301] *** updated
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://www.backuptoweb.co.uk/$1 [R=301]


# check if coming from mobile site
# if yes continue to main site

#  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www\.mobile\.backuptoweb\.co\.uk/ [NC] *** updated
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://mobile\.backuptoweb\.co\.uk/ [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.backuptoweb.co.uk$1 [R=301,L]


# send any remaining mobile visitors to mobile site

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{http_host}   !^$
# RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mobile.backuptoweb.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]  *** updated  
RewriteRule (.*) http://mobile.backuptoweb.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]


# rewrite non-www to www

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^backuptoweb\.co\.uk$
RewriteCond %{http_host}   !^$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.backuptoweb.co.cuk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: possibly, why is what I am asking not feasible?

Comment: I am dumb I forgot to remove the L from the redirects, not sure if its still quite right tho.

Comment: What you are wanting to do may well be feasible. It's difficult for me to see all the rewrite combinations you want to account for so I'm trying to simplify the scenario, get everything working and then work outwards from there. Good luck!

Comment: If you don't have any luck solving this, it would be helpful to me if you could give examples of what you want to achieve with all the rewrites, and also details of where the mobile directory is relative to your main site (same directory, sub-directory, completely independent)

Comment: What I want to do is redirect mobile traffic to the subdomain while keeping my canonical redirects when browsing the non mobile site and also the mobile users must be able to view the full site if they choose via a link from the mobile version. The mobile subdomain is in its own directory relative to httpdocs.

Comment: Yes you are correct with the above except that I need to keep the rule that converts index.php to / in the main site also.

Comment: The logic order looks ok to me

Comment: It seems to be in the right direction but its not quite right. Firstly its redirecting to www.mobile.backuptoweb.co.uk it should be just mobile.backuptoweb.co.uk. I changed that.  The second issue is that it removes all / from the address for example if I link to www.backuptoweb.co.uk/support it send you to www.backuptoweb.co.uksupport and lastly the seems to just keep looping back to the mobile site even when coming from the mobile back to the full site.

Comment: Hopefully we are on the right track.  See the 2 updates to address the mobile redirection issue, and I had a typo in my line which stripped index.php from the URL